# Creating NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

how i can create Dictionary that when i create jsondata with it, json looks like :

```
 "historyStep":[

{
"counter": "50",
"timestamp": "1461674383632"
}
 ]
```

I did this :

```
NSMutableDictionary*jsonDictOth = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[jsonDictOth setObject:@(810) forKey:@"counter"];
[jsonDictOth setObject:@"1464957395241.447998" forKey:@"timestamp"];
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictMain = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonDictOth,@"historyStep", nil];
NSError*error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictMain
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
```

but it looks :

```
 historyStep =     {
    counter = 810;
    timestamp = "1464957395241.447998";
};
```

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictMain create an array instead of this dictionary

Comment: You are missing a level: NSDictionary (top level) with NSArray of NSDictionary in the top level key "historyStep".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a level: `NSDictionary` (top level) with **`NSArray`** of `NSDictionary` in the top level key `historyStep`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *topLevel = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


NSArray *historySteps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//Here you may have a for loop in case there are more steps
NSDictionary *aStep = @{@"counter":@"50", @"timestamp":@"1461674383632"};
[historySteps addObject:aStep]

[topLevel setObject:historySteps forKey@"historyStep"];

NSError*error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:topLevel
                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                 error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like,

```
   NSMutableDictionary*jsonDictOth = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[jsonDictOth setObject:@(810) forKey:@"counter"];
[jsonDictOth setObject:@"1464957395241.447998" forKey:@"timestamp"];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[arr addObject:jsonDictOth];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictMain = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arr,@"historyStep", nil];
NSLog(@"jsonMain is %@",jsonDictMain);
NSError*error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictMain
                                               options:0
                                                 error:&error];
```

It's output is,

```
jsonMain is {
historyStep =     (
            {
        counter = 810;
        timestamp = "1464957395241.447998";
    }
 );
}
```

You just missed one array between

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *innerDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"50", @"counter",@"1461674383632", @"timestamp", nil];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:innerDictionary, nil];
NSDictionary *outerDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:array, @"historyStep", nil];
```

Use this code it will work perfectly.

Comment: Why so verbose?  What's wrong with Objective-C literals?